# React Native Android Native UI Components doesn't find @ReactProps

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-camera

i'm trying to implement my first react native UI component, i followed the Facebook tutorial and it should be easy but i have some strange problem

```
public class CameraViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<CameraPreview> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTCameraView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
         return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public CameraPreview createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        return new CameraPreview(context);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "test")
    public void setTest(CameraPreview view, @Nullable String test){
        Log.i("TESTWD", test);
    }

}
```

This is the ViewManager i'm using and to me it seems correct. The first problem is that android studio doesn't find @ReactProp and it doesn't compile. The second problem is that if i remove that method everything compile but when i use this component nothing appears

Comment: You need to `import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;` instead of `import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactProp;`

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this myself. The solution is as [if-else-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3432566/if-else-switch) pointed out in a comment above:

```
// Import this
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;

// Not this!
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactProp;
```

There seem to be two `@ReactProp` definitions in different packages and Android Studio chooses the wrong one by default.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using react-native 0.13.+ instead of 0.11.+